# unclosed <i> causing progressively more <i> in each <p>

Tags: html

I'm currently learning html5 specification and have encountered the following snippet in [syntax error section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/introduction.html#syntax-errors)  of the document

[image]

I understand that opening and closing tag of a html element must exist completely within its parent html element. e.g. `<div><p>hello</p></div>` is valid but `<div><p>hello</div></p>` is not.

But for the example in the screenshot, what is causing the progressively more `<i>` element in each `<p>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `<p>` start tag closes the open `i` and `p` elements, creates a new `p` element and recreates each `i` element closed by the `<p>` tag, (in a process known as [reconstructing the active formatting elements](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#reconstruct-the-active-formatting-elements)) and then the new `<i>` tag creates a new `i` element inside the recreated `i` elements, forming the nested `i` elements that you see.